# Trying to use regex expression in Notepad++ to match a particular pattern and replace it

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to localize a translation file for a patch; my packer requires the text formatted it in a certain way for his patching program to work.

The 5000+ lines text file is formatted in various blocks of text like:

```
Sentence
Sentence

Sentence
Sentence
Sentence

Sentence

Sentence
```

He needs the output to be

```
sentence\nsentence

sentence\nsentence\nsentence

sentence

sentence
```

I'm trying to use [.+\n.+] to replace with [$2"\n"$1] but it seems to match everything.

Comment: I'd use `([^\r\n])\R([^\r\n])` to replace with `$1\\n$2` since we have no clue as to what linebreaks you are having.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't understand, why capturing group? Is [`/.\n./g`](https://regex101.com/r/rD6eG7/3) wrong?

Comment: @Shafizadeh: You are matching and consuming the characters before and after a newline, so when you replace, these characters will get removed. Note that `.` does not match `\r` in Notepad++. So, if the linebreaks are CRLF, your regex won't find anything. Also, do not use the regex delimiters for a regex in Notepad++, it is not using any regex delimiters (it is using Boost library)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see, just one thing, `g` modifier is activate on Notpad++ ?

Comment: There is a *Replace All* button.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this pattern:

```
.\n.
```

And replace it with this:

```
\\
```

- `.` matches any character (except newline)
- `\n` matches a line-feed (newline) character
- **`g` modifier:** global. All matches (don't return on first match)

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD6eG7/3)

Comment: Where do you add the g modifier for the regex inside Nodepad++?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (on Windows with Dos formatting `\r\n`; in Unix only `\n` is needed in Find What) with

Find what : `(.)\r\n(.)` for Dos formatting

Find what : `(.)\n(.)` for Unix formatting

-- OR --

Find what : `(.)\R(.)` universally (thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460982/trying-to-use-regex-expression-in-notepad-to-match-a-particular-pattern-and-re#comment60534775_36460982), I didn't know this trick)

Replace with : `$1\\n$2`

Make sure `. matches newline` is not enabled. [See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlMml.png).

Answer (score 0):

Windows? Use this:

Search:

```
([^\r\n])\r\n([^\r\n])
```

Replace:

```
$1\n$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Replace Dialog:

- **Find what:** `(.)\r\n(.)`
- **Replace with:** `\1\\n\2`
- check **regular expression**
- click **Replace all**

Comment: Why capturing group? You can do that simple this this: [`/.\n./g`](https://regex101.com/r/rD6eG7/3)

Comment: @Shafizadeh Maybe in perl or awk, but imho not in Notepad++.